Is it possible to patent something that cannot be implemented yet?
Let's suppose that an invention combines three components A, B, and C in a way that produces an unexpected result.
However, component C can only be described at a high level and currently there is no known way to actually implement C.
Can this invention be patented?

No, it cannot. Enablement means the specification must describe how to make and use the invention to a person of ordinary skill in the art, without undue experimentation. In this case, since there is no known way to "make" the invention, the legal requirements for patentability are not fulfilled.

How do you explain https://patents.google.com/patent/US3781647A/en?oq=3%2c781%2c647 which was impossible to create with the technology available of the time?

@EricS Without even having to read the link, it should be clear that the patent office is allowed to make mistakes and grant a patent where there was in fact insufficient enablement.

That patent was filed by a well known technical consulting company Arthur D Little. It was impractical in 1971 and probably still is, but not impossible. And examiners rarely  question enablement except in. Cases of perpetual motion.

@GeorgeWhite I used to work at ADL. What is interesting about this patent is while it doesn't violate any laws of physics it was impossible to implement with the technology available at the time. I believe Peter Glaser and ADL were well aware it would never be built within the active lifetime of the patent. It did, however, cement his reputation as a visionary. Thus, the patent achieved its purpose.

No, not if is not possible to make.
But being impossible to make is not the same as being impractical to make. Something can be patented that is not cost-effective, reliable or otherwise unsuitable for production.
Later materials and techniques and even inventions can make an existing invention actually practical.
